# Hello friends how achieve bottom media controller layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello friends i am beginner in android i want know how to achieve this type layout the image which shown below please help me i trying achieve this type of layout

[image]

Comment: Whats so complicated in it ? Its just a Layout with Some Views . Have you tried anything ?

Comment: i tried but not very easy nilesh rathod

Comment: @maha post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is very simple layout FYI**

> It can be done with any type of parent layout Constraint, Relative and
>   even with Linear

I will share a Relative one example. Use your own drawables and assests.

```java
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSongTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonBackward"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Song Name - [details]"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewArtistName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewSongTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonBackward"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Singer Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonForward"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="F"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlayAndStop"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttonForward"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="PS"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBackward"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttonPlayAndStop"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="B"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```